# Binary Tree returning nulls for nodes

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree

I'm trying to build a binary tree recursively for an AI I'm developing.
I try to build a tree but everything comes back null. The language is Java and I'm using Eclipse. Also, I'm on a Mac if that means anything. The tree should be returned as a binary tree with nodes instantiated but without any content.

```
    public class DecisionTree {

        //build a generic, empty, tree
        //building binary

        Root r = new Root();

        public void build()  //ok
        {

            Node lhs = new Node();
            Node rhs = new Node();
            lhs = new Node();
            rhs = new Node();

            r.lhs = lhs;
            r.rhs = rhs;
            lhs.parent = r;
            rhs.parent = r;

            builtRecursion(lhs, 1);
            builtRecursion(rhs, 1);

            outputTree();
            int ctr = 1; //levels of tree           
        }

        public int builtRecursion(Node n, int ctr)
        {
            Node lhs = new Node();
            Node rhs = new Node();
            ctr++;
            System.out.println("built recursion ctr is " + ctr);
            if (ctr > 10)
            {
                //leaf node
                Behaviors behavior = new Behaviors();
                Node node = behavior;
                n.b = behavior;
                return 0;
            }

            n.lhs = lhs;
            n.rhs = rhs;
            lhs.parent = n;
            rhs.parent = n;

            builtRecursion(lhs, ctr);
            builtRecursion(rhs, ctr);

            return ctr;         
        }

        public void outputTree()
        {
            if (r != null)
            {
                System.out.println("Root");
            }
            outputTreeRecursive(r);
        }

        public void outputTreeRecursive(Node n)
        {
            if (n.lhs != null)
            {
                System.out.println("------------------");
                System.out.println("LHS");
                outputTreeRecursive(n.lhs);
            }
            else { System.out.println("LHS is null");}

            if (n.rhs != null)
            {
                System.out.println("-----------------");
                System.out.println("RHS");
                outputTreeRecursive(n.rhs);
            }
            else { System.out.println("RHS is null");}

            System.out.println("-----------------");
        }
}
```

ROOT CLASSS

```
    package FLINCH;

public class Root extends Node {

    Node lhs = new Node();
    Node rhs = new Node();
}
```

NODE CLASS

```
package FLINCH;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Node {

    Node lhs = null;
    Node rhs = null;
    Node parent = null;

    Decider d = new Decider(this);
    Behaviors b = null;

    public LinkedList getSuccessors()
    {
            LinkedList list = new LinkedList();

            list.add(lhs);
            list.add(rhs);
            return list;
    }

}
```

OUTPUT

```
GetAction Running
Iterating through open list
Size of open list is 1
Peeked openLIst size is 1
Peeking throguh open list
Popping Open List
LHS is null
RHS is null
Number of children is 2
Children equals 2
Decider childrens loop
Child node is null
Iterating through children
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at FLINCH.A_Star_Search.search3(A_Star_Search.java:81)
    at FLINCH.Soldier.search_behavior(Soldier.java:28)
    at FLINCH.Main.getAction(Main.java:54)
    at tests.GameVisualSimulationTest.main(GameVisualSimulationTest.java:52)
```

I hope this helps...

Comment: Only the leaves' left and right descendants should be printed as `null`. Share your output, as well as how you defined `Node` and `Root` (I assume `Root` extends `Node`, a class with  3 variables - `lhs`, `rhs` and `parent`?)

Comment: What do you mean "everything comes back null"?  Your algorithm looks fine, and when I tried it (with a smaller depth than 10), the output was what I expected.  I recommend you try it with 10 replaced by 2 or 3, then post the output and explain what about the output isn't what you expect.

Comment: ajb: the binary tree is instantiated down to a certain level. When I try to step through it, i start at the root and then go to the left hand side and right hand side, but this values are null, when they should be instances of Node objects and so on down the tree until it reaches the leaves. I tried it with values two through 10 and I get the same result

Comment: You're getting an `NullPointerException` in code you haven't shown us.  There's no way for us to help you since we can't see the code.

Comment: @TedGress I saw your edit on my post. the problem with your search is these lines: children.add(q.lhs); children.add(q.rhs); because you add to children without check if they are null or not and later you try to do operations on them which triggers NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

I have a piece of code which you can use for BinaryTree

```
public class BinarySearchTree {
public static  Node root;

public BinarySearchTree(){
    this.root = null;
}


public void insert(int id){
    Node newNode = new Node(id);
    if(root==null){
        root = newNode;
        return;
    }
    Node current = root;
    Node parent = null;
    while(true){
        parent = current;
        if(id < current.data){              
            current = current.left;
            if(current==null){
                parent.left = newNode;
                return;
            }
        }else{
            current = current.right;
            if(current==null){
                parent.right = newNode;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

public boolean find(int id){
    Node current = root;
    while(current!=null){
        if(current.data==id){
            return true;
        }else if(current.data > id){
            current = current.left;
        }else{
            current = current.right;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean delete(int id){
    Node parent = root;
    Node current = root;
    boolean isLeftChild = false;
    while(current.data!=id){
        parent = current;
        if(current.data > id){
            isLeftChild = true;
            current = current.left;
        }else{
            isLeftChild = false;
            current = current.right;
        }
        if(current ==null){
            return false;
        }
    }
    //if i am here that means we have found the node
    //Case 1: if node to be deleted has no children
    if(current.left==null && current.right==null){
        if(current==root){
            root = null;
        }
        if(isLeftChild ==true){
            parent.left = null;
        }else{
            parent.right = null;
        }
    }
    //Case 2 : if node to be deleted has only one child
    else if(current.right==null){
        if(current==root){
            root = current.left;
        }else if(isLeftChild){
            parent.left = current.left;
        }else{
            parent.right = current.left;
        }
    }
    else if(current.left==null){
        if(current==root){
            root = current.right;
        }else if(isLeftChild){
            parent.left = current.right;
        }else{
            parent.right = current.right;
        }
    }else if(current.left!=null && current.right!=null){

        //now we have found the minimum element in the right sub tree
        Node successor   = getSuccessor(current);
        if(current==root){
            root = successor;
        }else if(isLeftChild){
            parent.left = successor;
        }else{
            parent.right = successor;
        }           
        successor.left = current.left;
    }       
    return true;        
}

public Node getSuccessor(Node deleleNode){
    Node successsor =null;
    Node successsorParent =null;
    Node current = deleleNode.right;
    while(current!=null){
        successsorParent = successsor;
        successsor = current;
        current = current.left;
    }
    //check if successor has the right child, it cannot have left child for sure
    // if it does have the right child, add it to the left of       successorParent.
    //      successsorParent
    if(successsor!=deleleNode.right){
        successsorParent.left = successsor.right;
        successsor.right = deleleNode.right;
    }
    return successsor;
}

public void display(Node root){
    if(root!=null){
        display(root.left);
        System.out.print(" " + root.data);
        display(root.right);
    }
}


public static void printInOrder(Node root){

    if(root == null){
        return;
    }

    printInOrder(root.left);
    System.out.print(root.data+" ");
    printInOrder(root.right);
}

public static void printPreOrder(Node root){

    if(root == null){
        return;
    }
    System.out.print(root.data+" ");
    printPreOrder(root.left);

    printPreOrder(root.right);
}

public static void printPostOrder(Node root){

    if(root == null){
        return;
    }

    printPostOrder(root.left);

    printPostOrder(root.right);
    System.out.print(root.data+" ");
}


public static void main(String arg[]){
    BinarySearchTree b = new BinarySearchTree();
    b.insert(3);b.insert(8);
    b.insert(1);b.insert(4);b.insert(6);b.insert(2);b.insert(10);b.insert(9);
    b.insert(20);b.insert(25);b.insert(15);b.insert(16);
    System.out.println("Original Tree : ");
    b.display(b.root);      
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Check whether Node with value 4 exists : " + b.find(4));
    System.out.println("Delete Node with no children (2) : " + b.delete(2));        
    b.display(root);
    System.out.println("\n Delete Node with one child (4) : " + b.delete(4));       
    b.display(root);
    System.out.println("\n Delete Node with Two children (10) : " + b.delete(10));      
    b.display(root);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("********* Printing In Order *********");
    printInOrder(root);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("********* Printing Pre Order *********");
    printPreOrder(root);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("********* Printing Post Order *********");
    printPostOrder(root);
}
}

class Node{
   int data;
   Node left;
   Node right;  
   public Node(int data){
       this.data = data;
       left = null;
       right = null;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you call your `buildRecursion` with `ctr = 1`, you probably mean you want to build a tree with just one extra level and from your comment where you expect to build a leaf node, the condition needs to be modified. in your case the condition should be:

```
if (ctr == 1)
```

I made some changes to your function for better output:

```
    public void builtRecursion(Node n, int ctr)
    {

        System.out.println("built recursion ctr is " + ctr);
        if (ctr == 1)
        {
            //leaf node
            Behaviors behavior = new Behaviors();
            n.b = behavior;
            return;
        }

        Node lhs = new Node();
        Node rhs = new Node();

        n.lhs = lhs;
        n.rhs = rhs;
        lhs.parent = n;
        rhs.parent = n;


        builtRecursion(lhs, ctr--);
        builtRecursion(rhs, ctr--);

    }
```

About the problem regarding *I try to build a tree but everything comes back null*, well in your `outputTree` and `outputRecursion` you don't print anything instead of `"-----"`, `"LHS"`, `"RHS"` and in case you reach where there is no left or right node you will print "LHS/RHS is null" but you should know that with a leaf node this is an accepted behavior so when you reach the leaf nodes you should print their values instead. However you can change the outputTreeRecursive to the following:

```
    public void outputTreeRecursive(Node n)
    {
        if (n.lhs != null)
        {
            System.out.println("------------------");
            System.out.println("LHS");
            outputTreeRecursive(n.lhs);
        }
        else {
                 System.out.println("LHS is null");
                 if(n.b != null)
                     System.out.println("Leaf node");
             }

        if (n.rhs != null)
        {
            System.out.println("-----------------");
            System.out.println("RHS");
            outputTreeRecursive(n.rhs);
        }
        else { 
                 System.out.println("RHS is null");
                 if(n.b != null)
                     System.out.println("Leaf node");                 
             }

        System.out.println("-----------------");
    }
```

now probably you get better idea about your tree